# The nature of $(4x^3+6x^2+4x+1)^k$

Tags: recreational-mathematics

I am trying to identify the mathematical properties of this polynomial $(4x^3+6x^2+4x+1)^k$. Most of all I’ve been attempting to describe an actual relationship to binomial coefficients, such as binomial$(4,n)^k$, and it’s very nature itself. How would this polynomial be written in a ‘concise manner’ resembling the binomial properties instead of just terms? Such as the equivalent of writing binomial$(n,k)=n!/(k!(n-k)!)$...? On Wolfram the gamma function shows up many times, it’s use seems unsatisfactory, and too mathematically rigorous. I’ve tried several methods of finding a useful method for years; multinomials, examining Stirling numbers, Catalan numbers, and so on, and nothing seems to work. I’m not worried about the complexity, it just a matter of finding a better more elegant representation.

Comment: Note that you can rewrite that as $((1+x)^4-x^4)^k$

Comment: There's the multinomial formula (it's not as bad as it looks): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Theorem

Comment: I’ve noticed over the years how pascal’s triangle and the limiting behavior it represents to the polynomial (4x^3+6x^2+4x+1)^k, but I have never seen any mathematics resembling this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. You can use binomial coefficients as the thing is $(x+1)^4 - x^4.$ If you know how to write $(a-b)^k,$ you have a way to write $\left((x+1)^4 - x^4 \right)^k.$

Comment: I have haven’t seen that before, I was wrote (x^4+4x^3+6x^2+4x+1)-(4x^3+6x^2+4x+1)=x^4 once. I like your way better, but do you know how I can make it into more of a ‘binomial(n,k)’ kind of formula.

Comment: In further examination, an easier way to write (x^4+4x^3+6x^2+4x+1)^k-(4x^3+6x^2+4x+1)^k-(6x^2+4x+1)^k-(4x+1)^k-1?

Comment: Another note: if x=1, k=1? {16^n-15^n-11^n-5^n-1^n}. Trying to understand these properties compared to just 16^n, compared to binomial(n,k).

Comment: @MikeMoye  what are $(a-b)^3$ and $(a-b)^5 \; \; ?$

Comment: Sorry, I’m not sure? Something similar to binomial({3,5},n)? It eludes me.

Comment: (a-b)^k=sum_(j=0)^n (-1+a-b)^j binomial(k,j)?

Comment: @MikeMoye $(a-b)^3 = a^3 - 3 a^2 b + 3 a b^2 - b^3. $ Can you expand $(a-b)^5  \; \; ?$

Comment: a^5-5a^4b+10a^3b^2-10a^2b^3+5ab^4-b^5=(a-b)^5

Comment: (a-b)^8. I think I know where you’re going with this.